# Getting NotSupportedException when trying to set image from isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to set image for my tile in the background agent for my application:

```
ShellTile t = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

if (t != null)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine("Tiles", "test1.jpg");

    StandardTileData tile = new StandardTileData();
    tile.Title = "Title text here";
    tile.BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:\" + filePath, UriKind.Absolute);
    t.Update(tile);
}
```

but then on `t.Update(tile)` it throws `NotSupportedException` :-( Isnt the path ("isostore:\") correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Uri(@"isostore:" + filePath, UriKind.Absolute);`

Without the backslash.